# Observable (and cancelable) loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, observable, system.reactive

I'm creating an emulator. The core of the emulation runs in an infinite loop like this:

```
while (true) 
{
      UpdateMachineState();
}
```

I would like to introduce Reactive Extensions **to execute this loop into another thread** and to make it **cancelable**, but I'm completely lost.

Since my emulator is a GUI application (Universal Windows), I don't wan't to block the UI thread.

It should look like:

```
...
while (true) 
{
      if (machine.IsHalted) 
      {
          observer.OnCompleted;
      }

      observer.OnNext(machine.GetState());           
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
...
```

The created sequence would eventually complete when the emulator enters the "halted" state. Otherwise, it will keep pushing `States` (an object that represents its internal state) forever.

I've tried with `Observable.Create`, but the overload that provides a `CancellationToken` requires a `Task<Action>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it in Rx:

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
    var loop = scheduler.Schedule(a =>
    {
        UpdateMachineState();
        a();
    });

    Thread.Sleep(1);

    loop.Dispose();
}

public void UpdateMachineState()
{
    Console.Write(".");
}
```

The overload on `.Schedule` that I used takes a `Action<Action>` as the parameter. You simply call the inner action if you want the the action to be rescheduled - so the above code effectively creates the infinite loop.

You then call `.Dispose()` on the return from the `.Schedule` call to cancel the loop.

Another alternative is to use the `.Generate` operator:

```
var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();
var query =
    Observable
        .Generate(0, x => true, x => x, x => machine.GetState(), scheduler);

var subscription = query.Subscribe(x => Console.Write("."));

Thread.Sleep(1);

subscription.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks! You're the man! I've got it working! I've used the second approach. It seems if fits better with ReactiveUI.